# MMIO/PIO Info for Linux

Tags: linux, device-driver

Is there a *nix command that will give me all the `MMIO/PIO address space`
for a particular device (or all devices)?

Comment: So how do you read the output?

Comment: Did you have a look at man lspci?

Comment: Yes, still didn't help..

Answer (score 2):

Did you already tried:

```
cat /proc/ioports
cat /proc/iomem
```

According to the redhat manual, the first show you a list of currently registered port regions used for input or output communication with a device, while the second shows you the current map of the system's memory for each physical device